# React-Native-Navigation How to dynamically set header title before render/navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm relatively new to the react native and I come across an issue that I can't solve and can't even find something about it.

I have and simple app that has seven buttons, one for every day in a week and I want to navigate the Day Screen and display the day I clicked at in the header title, but the I tried passing the day as argument and then set it in aspect but this will update the title after the render with slight delay. I have tried it with Redux but it seems kinda complicated and there must be some easier way of doing this.

**EDIT**

This looks like it sets the header title before render, but it gives me a warning

> Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.

MainScreen Code

```
onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate("DayScreen", { name: title });
              }}
```

DayScreen Code

```
const [name, setName] = useState(props.route.params.name);
props.navigation.setOptions({ title: name });
```

Comment: with `useState` hook.

Comment: please show some sample code so i can help

Comment: you can try simple ways with passing params for title.           ```navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
            title: 'dynamic title',
       });```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `useLayoutEffect` hook [as advised](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#setoptions) in the React Navigation documentation:

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

const YourScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {

    // Pass the title as a parameter when navigating
    const { title } = route.params;
    
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            title,
        });
    }, [navigation]);
    
    // render something
    
};

export default YourScreen;
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, @digitalbreed. This does work -- but useEffect also seems to work. Is there a reason to use useLayoutEffect rather than useEffect in this case?

Comment: @stevehs17 the answer was written for React Navigation 5 - see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/navigation-prop#setoptions - RN6 advises to use useEffect, so just go with that.